# stuck in Foundation of Mathematics course

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, inequality

I'm studying Foundation of Mathematics on my own due to personal situation and can't go to class

---

In the Reference book that I'm studying there is one portion of problem solution I can't understand.
here is the problem. 
$$\{x^2 -3 | x \in [-5, 1)\} = [-3, 22]$$

I understand whole proof and it's not hard at all except the part that:
$$-5 \leq x \lt 1 \space \text{ then } -5 \leq x \leq 5$$
I don't know why ?

Comment: Because if $x < 1 < 5$, then $x \le 5$

Answer (score 1):

$1\lt 5$, so if $x<1$ then surely $x<5,$ which implies $x\le 5$

Comment: I thought about that but it occurred to me if we choose x to be 4, it's true for one and false for another. suppose my point of view is wrong :)

Comment: $x<1\implies x\le5$ but not ($x\le5\implies x<1$)

Comment: @Masoud : That’s ok. There is no claim that they are equivalent, only that one implies the other (not that each implies the other).

Comment: thank you all for your time, If you have any advise for deeply understand mathematics I'll be glad to hear it

Comment: Halmos:  “The only way to learn mathematics is to do mathematics.” ;  [von Neumann](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann):  "In mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them.  "

Comment: @Masoud Have you learned about mathematical logic (if then statements, etc)? That helped me a lot. For this particular question, the statement is “If x is a ‘random’ number between -5 and 1, then it is also true that that particular x is between -5 and 5.” Does that make sense?

Comment: @Blue I studied mathematical logic at set theory books, and I agree with you about mathematical logic it helps a lot, I that's the interpretation of mathematical notation that make sense. my mistake origin was when I supposed them are equal. but if we consider them as $p \to q$ it make sense . thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @Masoud oh ok ${}$

Answer (score -1):

Let $A= \{ x| -5 \le x < 1 \}$ and $B = \{ x|-5 \le x \le 5 \}$.

$$A \subset B$$

$$x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B.$$